# Automation account is linked to a workspace Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, account

I am trying to delete an automation account in Microsoft Azure.

When I run this command below, I get the error below :

```
Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName changed_resource_group_name -ResourceType Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts -ResourceName changed_resource_name ApiVersion 2015-10-31 -Force
```

I get the following error :

```
{
  "code": "Conflict",
  "message": "Automation account is linked to a workspace. SubscriptionId: changed_subscription_id AccountName: changed_automation_ac_name WorkspaceId: /subscriptions/...../providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/...."
}
```

Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb158610-a065-4cb9-b302-6230de5ca434/how-to-unlink-an-automation-account-that-is-linked-to-an-oms-workspace?forum=opinsights

Comment: No unfortunately Mark, that script does not work!

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, you need unlink your Automation account with workspace. You could do it on Azure Portal.

[image]

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-unlink-from-log-analytics).

After do it, you could remove your Automation account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a linked automation account to a Workspace, you need to first remove the solutions in OMS that use the Automation Account.

Azure Automation, Change Tracking and Updates are the solutions that use Automation account.

```
$automationSolutions = "Updates", "ChangeTracking", "AzureAutomation"

$enabledautomationSolutions = (Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsIntelligencePacks -ResourceGroupName $workspace.ResourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspace.Name).Where({$_.Name -in $AutomationSolutions -and $_.Enabled -eq $true})
```

Now remove each of the solutions:

```
foreach ($soln in $enabledAutomationSolutions.Name) {
        Set-AzureRmOperationalInsightsIntelligencePack -ResourceGroupName $workspace.ResourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspace.Name -IntelligencePackName $soln -Enabled $false
    }
```

After that, you can get the Resource ID of the Azure Automation account and delete it:

```
$automationAccount = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId ($workspace.ResourceId + "/linkedServices/automation") -ErrorAction Stop

Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $automationAccount.ResourceId
```

The MSDN website has a solution to this. Kindly follow the link given below:

[MSDN - How to unlink an automation account that is linked to an OMS workspace?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb158610-a065-4cb9-b302-6230de5ca434/how-to-unlink-an-automation-account-that-is-linked-to-an-oms-workspace?forum=opinsights)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this guidance, but in January it was "coming soon":

> 1. Navigate to the Automation Account that is linked to a workspace
> 2. Select the Overview node
> 3. Click the Unlink Workspace command (this is currently not available
>      and the tool tip shows 'coming soon')

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb158610-a065-4cb9-b302-6230de5ca434/how-to-unlink-an-automation-account-that-is-linked-to-an-oms-workspace?forum=opinsights

Comment: But I only want to remove the automation account, nothing else. I want to leave everything else in place

Comment: Modified my answer.